# JQuery - Find out what HTML Tag is $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I find out that `$(this)` is an `li`? Is there any jQuery function that will let us know what HTML tag it is?

```
<ul>
  <li class="data">Hello</li>
  <li class="data">World</li>
</ul>
```

```js
$('.data').each(function() {
   alert($(this).?); // Find what HTML Tag is in $(this)
});
```

Comment: `$(this)[0].tagName` or `this.tagName`

Answer (score 0):

To determine the type of the Element you can use the `tagName` property:

```js
$('.data').each(function() {
  console.log(this.tagName);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="data">Hello</li>
  <li class="data">World</li>
</ul>
```

Similarly you can use jQuery's `is()` method to check the given element against a selector:

```js
$('.data').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is('span')) {
    console.log('You clicked the SPAN!');
  } else {
    console.log('You clicked something else');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="data">I'm a span!</span>
<div class="data">I'm a div!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This could help you to identify what element type is..

```js
jQuery('.data').each(function() {
   console.log(this.nodeName);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="data">Hello</li>
</ul>
<p class="data">para</p>
<h1 class="data">Heading 1</h1>
```